# How to use ordinals using Dataset API (like SQL's 'GROUP BY 1' or 'ORDER BY 2')?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am able to use ordinals (these integers after `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`) in the Spark SQL 'literal' query:

```scala
sqlContext.sql("SELECT ProfileName, COUNT(1) FROM df GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC")
```

But with DataFrames/DataSets I have to always use the column names:

```scala
df.select($"ProfileName").groupBy($"ProfileName").count().orderBy(desc("count"))
```

I didn't find a way to use ordinals in DataFrames.

What I am looking for is something like:

```scala
df.select($"ProfileName").groupBy(1).count().orderBy(desc(2)) // WON'T COMPILE
```

Is there anything like that in Spark SQL I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // WON'T COMPILE

There is this distinction between two contexts in play here - the Scala compiler and Spark (the runtime).

Before you execute anything in Spark, it has to pass the Scala compiler (assuming your programming language is Scala). That's why people use Scala to have this extra safety net (heard about *"once a Scala application compiles fine, it's supposed to work fine too"*?)

When your Spark application is compiled, the Scala compiler will make sure that  the signature of `groupBy` is available so `groupBy(1)` is correct at runtime. Since there's no `groupBy(n: Int)` available, the compilation fails.

It could have worked fine if there were an implicit conversion from `Int` to `Column` type (but that would have been even *crazier*).

Given you use Scala, you can create values that you can share and so there's no need to offer such feature.

A very similar question is whether Spark SQL supports columns that would be the ordinals as in SQL, e.g.

```
df.select($"ProfileName").groupBy($"1").count().orderBy($"2".desc)
```

I don't know the answer (and neither would I appreciate such feature considering it a bit cryptic).

Answer (score 1):

The columns in dataframe are not accessible by index but, if you need to access by index you can do as below

```
df.select($"ProfileName").groupBy(df1.columns(1)).count()
  .orderBy(desc(df1.columns(1)))
```

*Note: The index starts from 0*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not exactly what is needed, because `df.columns` will return the array of the initial dataframe's columns, whereas I need to order by "count", which is not the part of `df`. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah @Vlad.Bachurin it does not work for the new schema, I did not noticed before :)